# Blurr screen occuring only with ubuntu(linux)

Tags: nvidia

My specs:
**Gigabyte m68mt-s2
4gb ddr3 sdram
amd phenom ii x4 840 processor
320gb hard drive
CRT monitor**
These are my system specifications, every time i install Ubuntu it works fine for some time and later it crashes and shows a blur screen and that's it, no response i have to reset with the button provided with the CPU.
Please confirm me whether my specs are capable of ubuntu or not,
With windows there is no such problem as explained above.
thank you

Comment: Your board has an integrated NVIDIA® GeForce 7025 graphics. Open Additional Drivers and install Nvida 304.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Michael Bay but i am already using Nvidia 304 proprietary driver in additional drivers tab.

Comment: What do you mean by "blur"? Perhaps you meant freeze, with unresponsive keyboard/mouse? That being the case, RAM and/or anything else in the motherboard is probably failing.

Comment: Blur in my case - the screen is covered with multiple line in any direction and unresponsive nature through out the system, i have to retrieve the system by pressing reset button only

Comment: It happening in 20.04LTS version
follow this comment
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242780/im-getting-blurr-screen-background-in-ubuntu-20-04lts